# $p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ is closed subgroup of $ \Bbb{Z}_p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I want to check $p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ is closed subgroup of $ \Bbb{Z}_p$.
It is clear that $p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ is subgroup of $ \Bbb{Z}_p$, I want to prove
$p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ is closed in $\Bbb{Z}_p$.

So, I only need to check $\Bbb{Z}_p\setminus p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ is open in $p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$.
Now,basis of $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ is $a +p^e \Bbb{Z}_p$($e≧0$) from the definition of p-adic topology. So, I only need to check $\Bbb{Z}_p\setminus p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ can be rewritten as union of $a +p^e \Bbb{Z}_p$($e≧0$).

How can I write $\Bbb{Z}_p\setminus p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ as union of $a +p^e \Bbb{Z}_p$($e≧0$)?

Comment: Use the fact that $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p = \{x\in \mathbb{Z}_p\,|\, v_p(x)\geq n\}$. What type of subset does this represent for the $p$-adic metric?

Comment: $p^n \Bbb{Z}_p＝${$x∈\Bbb{Z}_p  \mid |x|_p≦p^{-n}$} $⊂\Bbb{Z}_p$

Comment: So $\Bbb{Z}_p\setminus p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ is region outside disk of radius $p^{-n}$, but I think this cannot be union of union of $a +p^e \Bbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: The more interesting point is the converse: every nonzero closed subgroup of $\mathbf Z_p$ is $p^n\mathbf Z_p$ for some $n \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$. Let $U = \alpha + p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then $U$ is basic open by your definition, and we have $\alpha \in U\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_p\setminus p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$. To see the last inclusion, suppose that $x \in U \cap p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$. Since $x \in U$ we have $x \equiv \alpha \pmod{p^n}$, and since $x \in p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ we have $x \equiv 0 \pmod{p^n}$. Therefore, we get $\alpha \equiv 0 \pmod{p^n}$, so $\alpha \in p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$, which contradicts the definition of $\alpha$.

I think the point of Captain Lama's comment was that $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a closed ball (or disc/disk, depending on your terminology) by definition, so it is closed by standard theory.

Comment: Oh, thank you!, closed ball is closed subset in general  metric space, so my ways was detour. But is it impossible to answer my question, to rewrite the subset by the union of basis ?

Comment: It's not impossible - that's exactly what I've done. I showed that for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p\setminus p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$, there is some basic open $U_\alpha$, (I called it $U$ in the answer, but let's call it $U_\alpha$ for the purposes of this comment) with $\alpha \in U_\alpha \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_p\setminus p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then we have $\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus p^n\mathbb{Z}_p = \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$.

Comment: Your answer completely answered my question, I didn't notice that at first. Thank you so much. It seems essentially the same as the proof of 'closed ball is closed subset in metric space' , right ?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, it's the same proof; in general, when you're working in a metric space, the easy way to show that a set $S$ is open is by taking an arbitrary element $x\in S$ and showing that there is some open ball $U_x$ with $x \in U_x \subseteq S$. Then we can write $S = \bigcup_x U_x$ as a union of open balls, and we're done. That's how you prove that the complement of a closed ball is open, and it's the same thing I've done here.

Comment: In general topological group, open subgroups are also closed, so the title follows, correct ?

Comment: @kleinfour follows from what?

Comment: $p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ is open because basis of p$ \Bbb{Z}_p$ is {$a +p^n \Bbb{Z}_p|a∈\Bbb{Z}_p$}.

Comment: Please delete p from p$ \Bbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Yes I suppose it does follow from that too. Although to prove that open subgroups are closed requires essentially the same proof as the one I used, so I think my method is more direct